# Como deixar html transferível entre computadores sem perder hyperlink e imagens?

Tags: html

Comecei a programar a pouco tempo usando HTML e o meu maior problema é fazer um projeto e quando eu levo para ouros computadores demoro muito tempo mudando os caminhos de imagens e hyperlinks.

Como fazer com que os links não quebrem quando eu levar meu projeto pra outro computador?

Exemplo, no pc da minha empresa o link fica algo do tipo:

> D:\Users\Programador\Desktop\meu-projeto\images\logo.png

No meu pc fica

> C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\meu-projeto\images\logo.png

Comment: Se em cada computador que vc levar seu projeto os caminhos forem diferentes, vai ter que mudar os caminhos mesmo. Sua pergunta está muito vaga sem um código de exemplo para ser analisado.

Comment: Você vai ir aprendendo isso com o tempo. Geralmente se usa uma linguagem de programação que **gera** o HTML que será enviado pro _browser_, com isso será possível criar funções nesta linguagem, onde esta função será responsável por criar um link dinâmico (tanto para outras páginas, como para imagens, etc.) apenas sabendo qual é o recurso que você pretende linkar. Só com HTML é mais difícil de se fazer algo, provavelmente a melhor ideia é trabalhar com endereços relativos ao invés de absolutos, isso já dá uma flexibilidade **bem** maior, mas ainda assim não resolve todos os casos.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que quis dizer. Tente colocar um caminho relativo nas sua imagens, ou seja, o caminho ocorre a partir da página atual. Por Exemplo: `<img src="~/Content/images/logotipo.png" alt="Logo" />` neste caso, a partir do local do site, ele irá buscar esse caminho para a imagem

Comment: O estranho nessa pergunta é que a estrutura de diretórios e arquivos (caminhos) do site (HTML) não muda quando você carrega tudo junto para outro computador. Não sei o porquê em ter que alterar isso.

Answer (score 5):

Para evitar ou minimizar esse tipo de problema você pode usar caminhos relativos.

Para referenciar partir da "pasta" a qual foi aberto o arquivo, comece o caminho sem barras, exemplo:

Você tem a seguinte estrutura:

- index.html
- imagens (pasta)

  - logo.png
- outroarquivo.html
- pessoas (pasta)

  - pessoa.html

Sua tag `img` ficaria:

```
<img src="imagens/logo.png">
```

Seu hyperlink ficaria:
    Outro arquivo

Já a imagem no arquivo `pessoa.html` teria que "voltar" uma pasta para localizar o arquivos, exemplo:

```
<img src="../imagens/logo.png">
```

Você encontra mais detalhamento neste link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 0):

O problema real é você utilizar caminhos absolutos para mapear seus recursos no Html, recomendo utilizar caminhos relativos, dessa forma, ao trocar de máquina o problema não existirá

No seu caso, se o arquivo Html fica na pasta `D:\Users\Programador\Desktop\meu-projeto\` o caminho da página pode ser apenas `images\logo.png`, o sistema vai buscar a partir do caminho atual a pasta `images` e depois o arquivo `logo.png`, indiferente de onde esteja a pasta `meu-projeto`